# Rebuilding content access permissions upgrade D6->D7 stuck at 99.97%

Tags: users, nodes, migrations

Hello I'm having trouble finding why rebuilding content access permissions can't complete. It get stucked at 99.97% every time I try to run it. Everything else seems to work properly. Any idea? I'm migrating Drupal 6 to 7.

Thanks!

**Comment**

Okay the answer is go to node.module on line 3000 somehting and disallow batch_mode by passing FALSE. It will then work and you can revert at the end of the process

Comment: check server response time.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I'm on localhost so I dont think it has an effect.